# Firestore data model is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to save some data in firestore, the data consists of events, each event has a date and each some attendees.

What I'm trying to do now is model it like this `events/${eventDate}/${userEmail}` and then I would set this with the user's data. However when I try to set this data I get an error saying that the segment number should be even.

When I added another segment in the path (which I didn't want to do):

`events/${eventDate}/attendees/${userEmail}` I was able to set the data but I wasn't able to retrieve it (trying to retrieve all attendees of a given event date.

```
// insertion - this worked after some tweaking
this.db.collection('pickups').doc(pickupDate).set({ [email]: userData})


// deletion (this doesn't work - expects even number of segments)
this.db.collection('pickups').doc(`${pickupDate}/${email}`).delete()

// retrieval (works)
this.db.collection('pickups').doc(pickupDate).valueChanges()
```

Current delete:

```
 this.db.collection('pickups').doc(pickupDate).update({
        [email]: firestore.FieldValue.delete()
      })
```

What am I missing here? Isn't this supposed to be like regular JSON?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the actual code that's not working the way you expect.  Please also show the exact values of any variables that you're using to build the path.

Comment: And if you have already something in your database, please add the structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I added some code, I dont have anything in the DB right now.

Comment: With `FirebaseError: No document to update: projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/pickups/16-09-19}` you're missing the actual document, e.g. need to have something in order to update it. You can try .set() with merge=True, which will try to update and if nothing exists it will add the document.

Comment: Sorry there was an extra bracket in the delete. Now I don't get an error but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The path you're currently trying `events/${eventDate}/${userEmail}` is interpreted as a collection (events) then a document (eventDate) then another document (userEmail).

What you actually have is a collection, document within that collection, field within that document.

It looks like you're adding the email correctly (I would remove the brackets around the word email though), but trying to delete incorrectly. You delete fields like this:

```
var removeCapital = cityRef.update({
    capital: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
});
```

You can see the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields

The delete may look like this:

```
this.db.collection('pickups').doc(pickupDate).update({
     email: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
})
```

Comment: This isn't working. I have brackets around `email` because it's a variable. Maybe this is why your solution isn't working.

Comment: Presumably, the word email is not a variable as typically people want to reference by consistent keys. If you make the word email a variable, any time you want to reference the data within it, you will need to know the email.  Is it incorrect to assume you want to store the email under the "email" key, and instead you want to store some data under the dynamic email address?

Comment: I'm basically trying to have this `{pickups: {'10-9': {abc@gmail: {//user data }}, '11-09: ....}}`

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code that doesn't work, and what you're receiving as an error?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is delete a field out of a document.  However, this code you have:

```
this.db.collection('pickups').doc(`${pickupDate}/${email}`).delete()
```

is trying to build a reference to a collection, then delete it.  It's not correct to use `collection()` and `doc()` to reference fields in a document.  They are just used to build **references** to **documents** and collections.

If you want to delete a **field** in a document, first build a reference to the document that contains the field:

```
const ref = this.db.collection('pickups').doc(pickupDate)
```

Then update the document to indicate that you want the field removed:

```
ref.update({ [email]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete() }}
```

The way you reference [delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-delete) out of FieldValue is going to change based on how you have the SDK imported into your code.

See the [documentation on deleting fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields) for more information.

Comment: Please see Dan's answer and my comments

Comment: Put brackets around email as I've edited above. That's JavaScript syntax for substituting a variable as a name of a property.

Comment: Its not working, as per my edit in the OP. Nothing is happening

Comment: Your OP has a syntax error.  Too many close brackets. You can see it in the error message.

Comment: Yes I noticed and fixed that, now the delete just does nothing

Comment: How do you know that `firebase.FieldValue.delete()` is the right thing to use? That's not what the documentation or my sample uses.